# color issue with ggplot geom point and geom segment

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to make a simple plot from the following R data frame. I have copied a dput output of the dataframe below:

```
structure(list(troponin.cat = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15), percentage = c(0, 13, 29, 40, 47, 53, 
57, 60, 62, 65, 66, 67, 69, 70, 71, 78)), .Names = c("troponin.cat", 
"percentage"), row.names = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15+"), class = "data.frame")
```

The code for my plot is

```
plot.2 <- ggplot(data=cumsum, aes(x=troponin.cat, y=percentage))+
geom_point(colour="red", size=5)+
geom_segment(aes(yend = 0, xend = troponin.cat, colour="red", size=5))+
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1, 15, 1))+
geom_line(colour="red")+
theme_classic()
```

For some reason the color of the geom point is different to the  geom segment and I have no idea why??

Comment: You have ` colour="black"` in `geom_segment` and `colour="red"` in `geom_point`.  You also have an atomic color assignment in an `aes` string (in `geom_segment`). Also (as an aside) it's bad form (and potentially problematic) to use function names (i.e. `cumsum`) as R data object names.

Comment: Sorry I have updated the code...they should both be "red" ... But when the plot outputs the geom segment is a lighter shade of red...not sure why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you were trying to achieve?

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- structure(list(troponin.cat = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15), percentage = c(0, 13, 29, 40, 47, 53, 
57, 60, 62, 65, 66, 67, 69, 70, 71, 78)), .Names = c("troponin.cat", 
"percentage"), row.names = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", 
"7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15+"), class = "data.frame")

plot.2 <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=troponin.cat, y=percentage))+
  geom_segment(yend=0, aes(xend=troponin.cat), colour="#a50f15", size=5) +
  geom_point(colour="#a50f15", size=5) +
  geom_line(colour="#a50f15") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1, 15, 1)) +
  theme_classic()

plot.2
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks...kind off except I want all aspects to be deep red I.e. the geom segement, geom point and the connecting line. Is that possible??

Comment: more like that? The points really blend in with the bars this way (not something I'd personally choose to do)